# C# method group to bool?

Tags: c#, methods

I have created some code, but I can't find what's wrong with it. Here's the code:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyMethod) //<==underlines this and gives the error
        {
            //code
        }
        else
        {
            //code
        }
     }

    public bool MyMethod()
    {
        if (Form1.f >= 0.001)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

The error message I get:

> Cannot convert method group 'MyMethod' to non-delegate type 'bool'.
>   Did you intend to invoke the method?

Can someone help me with this problem? I can't seem to get it right, I've tried several things... I have also tried to change it to string and the return values to strings but that gives the same error (except the bool, that's changed into string). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make call function  `if (MyMethod())`

Comment: I think I am just stupid thank you all very much!

Comment: `if (something) return true; else return false;` is nothing but a long way of writing `return someting;`, by the way. Just use `return Form1.f >= 0.001;` and you're done.

Comment: instead of editing and put `Solved` in your question, accept the answer that actually solved your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`MyMethod` is not a field or property but a method. A method must be called with `()`:

```
if (MyMethod()){ ... }
```

You could make it a property, then you don't need them, f.e. as [expression-body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#property-get-statements):

```
public bool MyMethod => Form1.f >= 0.001;
```

Now you can use (choose more meaningful names):

```
if (MyMethod) { ... }
```

Comment: +1 for the language specific alternative to define `MyMethod` as property and actually use it as asked in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are effectively passing a delegate to the method rather than the result of the method. To invoke the method so that you are checking the result of the function, you need to add brackets at the end like so:

```
if (MyMethod())
```

Answer (score 2):

Very Simple mistake. You forgot to put `()` after method name, hence your parameter treated as a delegate and error invoked as it couldn't convert to  non-delegate type of 'bool'.

```
if (MyMethod()) //<==corrected  the error
{
    //code
}
else
{
    //code
}
```